# Segmentation fault strcmp in c

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, strcmp

I'm trying to run a program in c that takes in a text file and string from the user and then searches the file for that string.  It keeps getting a segmentation fault and gdb is pointing me towards this function but I am not sure what the problem is. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the `strcmp` call but I am not sure. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
int inTable( const char *s )
{
    int i;

    for( i=0; i<numLines; ++i )
    {
        if( strcmp( st[i], s ) == 0 )
                return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: st is the file that is read in using fgets()

Comment: @user4959809 , Is `st` a `FILE*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check that you properly use `strcmp()`, the API is:

```
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

You must:

1) Validate that `st[i]`, your first argument is a pointer.

2) Make sure that `st[i]` & `s` has the Null terminator '\0'`.

3) Check that `st[i]` & `s` pointing to an allocated place in the memory before calling `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check s:

```
int inTable(const char *s) 
{
     if (s == NULL)
     {
          return 0;
     }

     // invoke strcmp
}
```

make sure const char *s is terminated with '\0